# How to use @font-face on a Chrome Extension in a Content Script

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, google-chrome-extension, font-face

Since I can't use `chrome.extension.getURL()` on a CSS file, how can I use @font-face with a local font file?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is how to get local path in css:

```
body {
  background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/background.png');
}
```

More about it [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n).

Comment: There is a bug on some Chrome versions which prevents this from working.
The quick fix: Use your extension id hardcoded instead of "__MSG_@@extension_id__".
The bummer is that when testing locally it won't work.

Comment: Don't forget to add fonts to https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources !!

Comment: Avoid spaces in the filename as these may result in a mismatch with the corresponding `web_accessible_resources` entry.

Answer (score 25):

This solution finally worked for me:

It injects a style node into the document of the content script.

And for Font Awesome, you only need the .woff src for Chrome.

[Adding @font-face stylesheet rules to chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015074/adding-font-face-stylesheet-rules-to-chrome-extension)

My code:

```
var fa = document.createElement('style');
    fa.type = 'text/css';
    fa.textContent = '@font-face { font-family: FontAwesome; src: url("'
        + chrome.extension.getURL('lib/fa/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3')
        + '"); }';
document.head.appendChild(fa);
```

In your manifest:

```
"css":[
    "lib/fa/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    ...
    ]

"web_accessible_resources":[
    "lib/fa/fonts/*",
    ...
    ]
```

Comment: Note: `"css": [...]` goes inside `"content_scripts": [...]`

Answer (score -2):

Old question, but this I think is the best solution:

[Firefox extension custom fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357596/firefox-extension-custom-fonts)

It applies equally for chrome extensions because rather than pointing to a font file, you're including the base64 encoded version of the font right in the CSS.

Answer (score -3):

Just use a relative URL. It's simpler, cleaner, and is The Right Thing To Do™:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
}
```

I know this question is old but it's a top result on Google and the accepted answer is inefficient.

**EDIT:** It seems that others are getting mixed results for this. I should mention that it probably doesn't work when used in Content Scripts. I've tested this in Popup Scripts and it works fine.

Comment: @Layke The path is relative to the CSS file location. I've simplified the example so you will probably still need to specify a `format()`.

Comment: This one doesn't work. It tries to find resource on Actual Web Page content script running at.

Comment: This is not intended for content scripts, it will only work in popup browser actions.

Comment: Question is specifically about content scripts, where this does not work.

Comment: It seems the question's title was edited long after I made this answer.

Comment: If the user wasn't using a content script the problem as described wouldn't be a problem. So I would say that this answer is somewhat distracting.

Comment: Has anyone managed to get font-awesome working with content-scripts?