# Adding @font-face stylesheet rules to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, font-face, content-script

What is the recommended way to add a @font-face stylesheet rule through a chrome-extension?  The problem is that the url of the font embed is located from within the extension, so I must do it in javascript in order to use `chrome.extension.getURL`.

I have tried `document.styleSheets[0].addRule` through a content-script, but that did not work.  To clarify, I also have the font listed under web_accessible_resources.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Inject a `<style>` node, in your content-script.  Something like so:

```js
var styleNode           = document.createElement ("style");
styleNode.type          = "text/css";
styleNode.textContent   = "@font-face { font-family: YOUR_FONT; src: url('"
                        + chrome.extension.getURL ("YOUR_FONT.otf")
                        + "'); }"
                        ;
document.head.appendChild (styleNode);
```

Comment: This finally worked for me, thanks! If using Font Awesome it's only necessary to link to the .woff for Chrome support.

Comment: Finally fixed my issue as well. I was using the Shadow Dom and my @font-face rule was in the CSS. Pulling it out and adding it directly to the dom solved it.

Comment: This way is pretty straightforward. Thanks! It works nice.

Answer (score 18):

You can also specify any additional stuff your extension uses in manifest.json in `web_accesible_resources` section. Docs are [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Add this into your manifest.json file:

```
 "web_accessible_resources": [
    "fonts/*.*",
    "templates/*.html"
 ]
```

And also correct urls in your css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/font.eot') /* ... */;
}
```

Comment: Simple and intuitive +1

Comment: Great advice, nice, clean and straightforward, and most importantly, no scripts. Cheers.

Comment: if you want to know why that weird string works: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n

Comment: For anyone on Manifest V3, the syntax for the manifest.json has changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191143/manifestv3-invalid-value-for-web-accessible-resources-or-resources-must-be-l