# Include ttf files in chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, font-face, content-script

I am using a content script to inject some HTML into a webpage. I am trying to use the google font, CabinCondensed-Regular, and a number of icon fonts gotten from IcoMoon. I have downloaded the files and am including them in the CSS with `@font-face`, because from what I can tell it's faster, but I don't know how to include them in the manifest.json. Normally you could specify a file by 
"content_scripts": [

```
{
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
    "css":["style.css", "jquery-ui.css"],
    "js":["jquery-2.1.0.min.js", "index.js", "jquery-ui.min.js"],
}
```

but as far as I can tell there is no specific tag for fonts, so how can I include the ttf files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you can use `"web_accessible_resources"` to link your font files (instead of `"content_scripts"`. Then just make sure your `@font-face` path is correct to the font files. See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Comment: When I try that I will either get "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html:" or "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "

Comment: Is your path to the fonts inside your CSS that declares `@font-face` correct? i.e. does the URL include the unique chrome extension ID? See a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535816/how-to-use-font-face-on-a-chrome-extension-in-a-content-script